# Antialiasing shapes in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, antialiasing

I'm using Pygame to draw some things. The problem is that they have a lot of aliased edges:

[image: Aliased concentric circles]

I want to make them softer, like this:

[image: Smooth concentric circles]

---

My idea so far was to draw the shape in double size, and then use

```
pygame.transform.smoothscale(surf, (w/2, h/2))
```

to shrink it to the size I want.

Unfortunately if I'm drawing my shapes on a transparent surface, the smoothscale turns the edges that were touching transparent pixels black!

- How do I smoothscale a picture without turning alpha-transparent pixels into black, or
- How else do I antialias edges?

Comment: Runnable sample please.

Comment: I haven't used Pygame in a while, or much at all, but would it be possible to make a new image which contains the part of the background it's meant to be on top of, scaled up, with the sprite superimposed, and then shrink and blit *that*?

Comment: There is a method for drawing antialiased circles (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html). Can you use that to draw a circle around your filled circle?

Comment: my shape is not a circle... johncip has a really good idea, but if possible I prefer a method that doesnt include taking a subsurface, double-sizing it and shrinking it again (it takes more time) but for now I'll use it! thanks

Comment: @superGeek if johncip's idea works, then great. Also, FYI the link I posted also has other antialiased shapes (ellipse, triangle and polygon).

Comment: @elParaguayo about the link, thank you very much but the shape i'm drawing is not common and made from the combination of a few filled ellipses. johncip's idea is kind of working, but it is slower than i want it to be, and also raises a problem that the rest of the shape's surface is not transparent anymore...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order to draw antialiased filled shapes with pygame, use the module `gfxdraw` and draw one antialiased outline and one regular filled shape.

From https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html:

> To draw an anti aliased and filled shape, first use the aa* version of the
> function, and then use the filled version.

Note that you need to import `gfxdraw` explicitly, i.e. `from pygame import gfxdraw`.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I need a half of an ellipse. I guess for now I'll just draw the whole ellipse and use a half of it...

Answer (score 12):

Here's a practical solution for andreasdr's answer.

```py
import pygame
from pygame import gfxdraw

def draw_circle(surface, x, y, radius, color):
    gfxdraw.aacircle(surface, x, y, radius, color)
    gfxdraw.filled_circle(surface, x, y, radius, color)
```